# How can I use associated constants in a where clause?

Tags: rust

The following seems like a bug to me.

```
struct Seq([u8; 8]);

impl From<[u8; 8]> for Seq {
    fn from(data: [u8; 8]) -> Seq {
        Seq(data)
    }
}

trait Sequence {
    const LEN: usize;
}

impl Sequence for Seq {
    const LEN: usize = 8;
}

trait ByteSequence {
    fn check();
}

impl<S> ByteSequence for S
where
    S: Sequence + From<[u8; <S as Sequence>::LEN]>,
{
    fn check() {}
}
```

Results in the following error: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=95ffa2f49c39c26a415d370fb538a90f&version=stable)

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `S: Sequence` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:23:29
   |
23 |     S: Sequence + From<[u8; <S as Sequence>::LEN]>,
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Sequence` is not implemented for `S`
   |
   = help: consider adding a `where S: Sequence` bound
   = note: required by `Sequence::LEN`
```

I also tried adding the bound in an extra line or directly in the impl declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a *bug*, it just hasn't been implemented yet. [Generic associated consts can't currently be used to parameterize fixed array lengths](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42863). You could perhaps file another issue for the not-so-useful error message (there has been at least [one other poor error message](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44243)).